# How to export an array to excel in r

Tags: r, arrays, excel

I want to export an array of multiple matrices to excel without merging them to one table. How would you do this?

example:

```
vector1 <- c(5,9,3)
vector2 <- c(10,11,12,13,14,15)

array <- array(c(vector1,vector2),dim = c(3,3,2))

write.csv(array,"array.csv")
```

This however merges the two matrices into one, I would like them eather  in different sheets or with space between them.

I'm new to R and Stackoverflow, so I hope this example and question make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the array to dataframe and export it to an excel file.

```
library(magrittr)
library(openxlsx)

array <- array(c(vector1,vector2),dim = c(3,3,2)) %>% as.data.frame()

write.xlsx(array, file = "array.xlsx", sheetName = "array")
```

Comment: thank you! But this still results in one table, I would like the two vectors to be separate in the excel sheet. For example in different sheets, or with spacing between them. Any suggestions for that?